# How to solve $\lim_{x\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{x}}{16x-x^2}$

Tags: limits

Solve the following question :

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\lim_{x\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{x}}{16x-x^2}\\
> \end{eqnarray}

The answer should be $\frac{1}{128}$.

I try that:

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\lim_{x\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{x}}{16x-x^2} &=& \lim_{x\to 16} \frac{(4-\sqrt{x})(4+\sqrt{x})}{(4\sqrt{x}-x)(4\sqrt{x}+x)(4+\sqrt{x})}\\
> \\ &=& \lim_{x\to 16} \frac{16-x}{(4\sqrt{x}-x)(4\sqrt{x}+x)(4+\sqrt{x})}\\
> \end{eqnarray}

What can I do?

---

***Thank you for your attention.***

Comment: Just note that $16x-x^2=x(16-x)$; can you simplify, now?

Comment: Use the above comment and the "difference of two squares identity"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting $\sqrt x=h,$

We have $$\lim_{h\to4}\frac{4-h}{16h^2-h^4}=\lim_{h\to4}\frac{4-h}{h^2(16-h^2)}=\lim_{h\to4}\frac{4-h}{h^2(4-h)(4+h)}=\lim_{h\to4}\frac1{h^2(4+h)}=\cdots$$  Cancelling  out $4-h$ as $4-h\ne0$ as $h\to4$

Comment: Now that I notice the down vote, I would request to pinpoint the mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

$$(4\sqrt{x}-x)(4\sqrt{x}+x)(4+\sqrt{x})=\sqrt{x}(4-\sqrt{x})\cdot \sqrt{x}(4+\sqrt{x})^2=x(16-x)(4+\sqrt{x})$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it the way you started, as follows:

$$\frac {4-\sqrt x}{16x-x^2}\cdot \frac {4+\sqrt x}{4+\sqrt x}=\frac {16-x}{x(16-x)(4+\sqrt x)}=\frac 1{x(4+\sqrt x)}$$

You made it too complicated by factoring the bottom (denominator) the way you did. With the limit at $16$, look to cancel a factor $(x-16)$. You can also cancel $4-\sqrt x$ directly and obtain the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use L Hospital's rule since it is in 0/0 form.